# CSS triangle border using :after pseudo selector rendering bug

Tags: css, geometry, border

In Firefox and IE when I use CSS border triangle solution with the `:after` pseudo selector the border looks frayed. See this image for a comparison:

[image: WebKit]
[image: triangle renderings]

This is from Chrome and Firefox. The relevant code is as follows:

```
li.active::after {
   content: "";
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -8px;
   left: 40%;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 8px 10px 0 10px;
   border-color: #FFF200 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: it's tipical but ok, look up

Comment: that is a rendering issue of the browser itself and not a css problem. Do, there is not much you can change on the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the way Firefox renders diagonal lines with aliasing. The easiest fix would be to simply change the shape of the triangle slightly so that all the border widths are the same and shift it up to compensate for the difference in size.

```
li.active::after {
   content: "";
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -6px;
   left: 40%;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
   border-color: #FFF200 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the transparent with:

rgba(255,242,0,0)

That worked for me.